# i want to created a folder with current date and copy files local ec2 instance to newly created folder , i want to automated this for every day

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup, unix-timestamp

I am trying to automate a backup process, so in my current ec2 Linux instance in /var/opt/.../backup-daily folder they will be jar file, so I want them to be copied into a newly created folder with current timestamp, and then zip the file, and copy the zip file into s3 bucket, and later on I want to delete the folder, which is 90days old,  pls provide me a Linux script

I am manually updating this process, but I need a script that runs daily at 10:00 am every day., my boss asked me to write a script to automate it

```
retentionDate=(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=90)).date()
sourceDirectory="give the directory where folder will be created with dateandtime"
```

I couldn't automate the process, all I need is to create a new folder with time stamp and copy all the jar files from the backup folder to the timestamped folder and then, the folder should be zip the files and then upload into an s3 bucket, and delete the files after 90days

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that StackOverflow is a site for asking programming-related questions. It is not a site for asking other people to write code for you. Feel free to edit your question and show the code you have currently written and let us know what specific problem you are experiencing and we will try to offer assistance. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

try this script with some changes:

```
#!/bin/bash
origin_dir="/var/opt/backup"
dest_dir=$(date +"/data/bkp_%F" -u)
log=$(date +"/data/bkp_%F.log" -u)

#send every output to log file
exec >> $log 2>&1

#copy the files do newer timestamped dir
cp -v $origin_dir/*.jar $dest_dir/

#zip files
bzip2 -v --compress --best $dest_dir/*.jar

#delete older dir with more than 90 days
find /data/ -type d -name 'bkp_*' -mtime +90 -exec rm -r -v {} \;
```